# protect credential in strings.xml inside apk file

Tags: android, security, obfuscation, credentials, android-obfuscation

When I decompile apk file of my app I see a lot of credential added by 3rd party libraries, and I believe its security issue:

```
<resources>
    <string name="default_web_client_id">123456.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">1234567890</string>
    <string name="facebook_client_token">12345678901234567890</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb1234567890</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url">https://work-ua-oauth.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">1234567890</string>
    <string name="google_api_key">12345678901234567890</string>
    <string name="google_app_id">1:1234567890:android:1234567890</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key">12345678901234567890</string>
    <string name="google_storage_bucket">my-app-ua-oauth.appspot.com</string>
</resources>
```

Is it ok to store it there?
Is there any way to obfuscate them or move to another place?